# How to copy var from function 1 to function 2?

Tags: jquery

I try to copy the `var1` from the first function to the second function, but I do not get any `alert()` back

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var var1;
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
    success: function(response) {
      var data = response;
      var1 = data.ip;
      $('#test').html(var1);
    }
  });

  // I want the var1 to be copied to the second function, to this:
  // The alert is for example, but it does not give me anything back

  $(function() {
    var var2 = var1;
    $('#test2').html(var1);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: "http://mywebsite.com/testip?"+var2, // just some query that i need to use with the ip from var1
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(var2);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evu3dat0/

Comment: You can't "copy" a local variable to another local variable that do not share a scope.  You have to move one of them to a higher scope that they both can use.   However, this also begs the question of why you have two document readies, rather than just one?  `$(document).ready(fn)` and `$(fn)` are effectively the same thing in jQuery.

Comment: One obtains the IP and the other one should send a request to the address: http://mywebsite.com/testip?"+var2 with the IP. Then testip.php saves the query (var2) into a txt file. I did not find another way to save var directly to a txt file

Comment: You didn't address why you must have two document readies vs just one.  Nothing about what you said requires two document readies.

Comment: Please **always properly indent code** you post on StackOverlow.

Comment: So I'm supposed to replace the $(document).ready with $(function(){?

Comment: Just combine the two things into one document ready.  Then the var1 or var2 variable scoped to the document ready is available to all the nested logic.

Comment: Or you can make var1 global by removing `var` and it will available below but still, in this case `var var2 = var1` will run before `var1 = data.ip` because ajax will take some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should combine your document readies into one, as you only need one.

Second, you can't perform the logic as you were trying to do so.  Ajax is **asynchronous**.  This means you would start the first request, and before it finishes, you were also going to attempt the second request.  Since the second request needs data from the first's response, this is invalid logic.

To fix this, you can call the second ajax method from the first's success, at which point the data will be available for it to use in the second ajax request.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var var1;
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
    success: function(response) {
      var data = response;
      var1 = data.ip;
      $('#test').html(var1);

      //I want the var1 to be copied to the second function, to this:
      //The alert is for example, but it does not give me anything back
      $('#test2').html(var1);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "http://mywebsite.com/testip?" + var1, // just some query that i need to use with the ip from var1
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          alert(var1);
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you. Now it works well. I will study the changes first